# Retrieving a specific field from Django query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to get the `type` field from filtering by `name`. So I am trying to do something like:`Example.objects.get(type).filter(name_exact="Sheep")` and it should return `Animal` But its not successful.

**models.py**

```
class Example(models.Model):

    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY_TYPE) #i.e Class, Type, Commodity, Market, Breed
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 

    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the type field of an instance:

```
t = Example.objects.get(name="Sheep").type
```

The `get(name="Sheep")` returns an example instance so you can do:

```
obj = Example.objects.get(name="Sheep")
print obj.type
print obj.name
obj.name = "Whatever" # assign new value to name
obj.save()            # save the changes to the db
```

On the other hand, if you need to do that with a queryset rather than with an object instance, you can use the `values` or `values_list` functions (examples extracted from the docs):

```
>>> Blog.objects.values('id', 'name')
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog'}]
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', 'headline')
[(1, u'First entry'), ...]
```